# Wait for node asynchronous operation

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

I want to use [search-index](https://github.com/fergiemcdowall/search-index) to index about 20 directories with about 10,000 files in each.  I expect the operation to take hours and all of the data could not fit into memory, and I'd like to batch the adds into say ten or twenty at a time.

The basic code looks like this, creating a search index and executing a callback function when it's ready that has the instance 'si' here:

```
searchIndex(siOptions, (sierr, si) => {
  // here I list the files and want to do batch adds:
  while (true) {
    var batch = getBatch();
    if (!batch) break;
    si.add(batch, options, (err) => {
      console.timeEnd('batch');
    });
  }
});
```

So my basic thought was to loop through directories, write out that I'm processing that directory, list the files, and process the files in batches of say 20 at a time:

```
_.each(subDirs, dir => {
  // list files
  // pull 20 files at a time
  // do add above
});
```

So I know how I *can* do it, but dang it looks ugly.  Being able to make this run synchronously would be ideal, but is there some utility library I could use?  My idea would be to create a function to handle a directory and go through one at a time, and increment the counter inside the callback and call itself...

```
var dirIndex = 0;
var doDir = function(cbDir) {
  if (dirIndex >= dirs.length) cbDir(); // done
  var batches = _.chunk(fs.readdirSync(dirs[dirIndex]), 20);
  var batchIndex = 0;
  var doBatch = function(cbBatch) {
    if (batchIndex >= batches.length) {
      cbBatch();
      return;
    }
    console.time('batch');
    si.add(batch[batchIndex++], options, (err) => {
      doBatch(cbBatch); // process next batch, have it call our callback
    });
  };
  doBatch(() => doDir(cbDir)); // final callback will do next dir
}
```

It seems like I might be opening up myself to problems with variable scope among other things.  Is there a better way?  I'm assuming all the time that search-index won't have a problem because the function `searchIndex(siOptions, (sierr, si) => {` has returned before all the operations have completed...

Comment: The two first thing that come to mind are either [`async`](http://caolan.github.io/async/) or Promises. `async` would modify a good part of your code, but keep it nice, clean and asynchronous. Promises are preferred nowadays, and I've seen them used to "synchronify" code, so may be a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setTimeout() if you want to run your code synchronously